# Full width banner in Bootstrap / WordPress?

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Is there an easy way to make a full width hero type banner using bootstrap and WordPress?    I know how to do it with bootstrap and I know how to hack WordPress Templates, the problem lies when you are wanting to this within the WordPress content editor(Perhaps via short-code even).

So, if using a template in wordpress that is say 1100 px wide, but the screen is 1300px wide, simple adding a div with a background color will only extend the width of the containing element which is 1100 px wide.

How can I add a fullwidth banner anywhere in the code with any sized containing element without breaking bootstrap rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `position: absolute` to break free from the containing div.

Then use `left: 0px; width: 100%` to use the full width of the browser.

Then, wrap your hero inside that.  So:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; width: 100%;">
  <div class="hero-unit">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>etc.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem you'll experience with this is that subsequent content will ignore this new div with regards to vertical-positioning.

A hack to that would be to add block-level content with the proper height adjustment (matching the height of your absolute-positioned div), e.g.

```
<div style="height:500px"></div>
```

Comment: Makes sense.   Might need to use external css so I can use media queries to hack in the exact height as it will change for various responsive states?

Comment: Also if any of the containers are positioned relative, this may not break all the way out to full width correct?

Comment: @Marty Right.  You should ensure you don't have a relatively positioned ancestor.  And using media queries to hack the height adjustment would probably work, if you're not displaying a fixed-height banner.